# Why is my shell slow after a while when I use git aware prompt and run git commands?

Tags: command-line, bash, git

I am using [git-aware-prompt](https://github.com/jimeh/git-aware-prompt) in my `.bash_profile` on Ubuntu 15.4 like this:

```
export GITAWAREPROMPT=~/.bash/git-aware-prompt
source $GITAWAREPROMPT/main.sh
```

When I am in one of my main repository directories this nicely shows the git branch in my prompt. However, after a few days (I do not restart my box often) it takes a long time after I run a command until the prompt comes back.

Especially when I run commands like `git add foo` or similar. It takes over a second for the next line of prompt to show up. Even if I open a new terminal window it is still slow.

If I navigate to a different git repo this does not happen. In directories without git it's also fine.

I don't think it's related to the git-aware-prompt, but rather to the repository. There might be some weird cache that I do not know about.

What can I do to make this go fast again?

Comment: Does it happen in a new terminal, too? Whould running `git gc` in the repo help?

Comment: @choroba: In a new terminal window it happens too. What does `git gc` do?

Comment: I ran the garbage collection. That helped a bit. Let's say it gave me a 50% performance boost, but I can still feel the difference between being in a git directory and for example my homedir.

Comment: You say you don't think that this is related to git-aware-prompt, and that it doesn't happen in another repository. Do you see this behavior even when you *don't* source the `git-aware-prompt` script? If yes, it probably has nothing to do with git-aware-prompt at all. If no, it may be related to a combination of that particular repo and git-aware-prompt (as git-aware-prompt makes a few `git`calls before you are returned to the prompt.)

Answer (score 7):

You can debug [why git is being slow](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/wiki/Diagnosing-why-Git-is-so-slow).

There are some ways to improve git performance:

- Enable git parallel index preload. `git config --global core.preloadindex true`
- Minimize the number of files in .git folder. `git config --global gc.auto 256`
- Run git garbage collector `git gc`.
- [Remove untracked files](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clean) `git clean -xf`. Use `git clean -xfn` for a dry-run to check that everything is ok.